# after I disconnect the media, it still replies when I ping it

Tags: networking, ping

I change the IP address to 192.168.1.1 in IPv4 for the ethernet adapter. However, after I disconnect the device, it still replies from 192.168.1.1 when I ping 192.168.1.1. How can it reply without the connection?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNCRD.png)

Comment: If I get you right, you're pinging the device at *your end* of the unplugged cable. Why shouldn't it respond?

Comment: I bet the ping time is really fast, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are pinging your own IP address. You can think of it this way:

The ping gets to your network adapter, and the network adapter looks at it and says "Hey! That's me. I don't need to send this down the wire to anyone else. I can answer the ping myself".

So, it doesn't matter if your network cable is unplugged -- the ping still receives a response.

Comment: so is there a way to find out the IP address of the device?

Comment: @WardenHuang, If by "device", you mean the Windows machine that the screenshots are from, its IP address is 192.168.1.1.